# Odoo - Change domain on inherited view

Tags: python, filter, odoo

I am currently working on building a custom module, and I extended the unit of measure class (product.uom).  I want some uom entries to be removed from the list/tree views, based on a specific value for one of my new variables.

I am not entirely sure how to modify this view.  I seem to be reading that I need to specify a domain, like domain = [("myvariable","=",True)], but I'm not entirely sure how to apply this.  I tried inheriting the tree view, and adding a domain, but this doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solution:

```xml
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="uom_list_action">
    <field name="name">Units Of Measurement</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.uom</field>
    <field name="domain">[("myvariable","!=",True)]</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="product.menu_product_uom_form_action">
    <field name="action" ref="uom_list_action"/>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="stock.menu_stock_uom_form_action">
    <field name="action" ref="uom_list_action"/>
</record>
```

Comment: So you want the entire row in the list/tree view to not display based on myvariable=True or you want a field in the row to not appear based on this condition?

Comment: Yep, that is what I'm trying to accomplish..

Comment: Which one the row or the field.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I msiread your comment.  I want the entire record to either be displayed, or not displayed, based on the value of the row the database.

Comment: And is this a tree/list within a form view or a full page list view?

Comment: To elaborate, all UoM records that have myvariable=true should not be listed in the tree view when you go into the Units of Measure menu.

Comment: Its for the full page list view...

Comment: Im going to try something. brb

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.  Also, if you or anyone else has any resources that go into detail for Odoo views, I'd appreciate it.  They have a module builder tutorial in the official documentation, but its very basic.

Comment: Sorry. I am going to have to look at this later. I have an appointment. Try going into Settings --> Actions --> Window Actions and editing the Domain Value for the records.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this using inheritance. I will try later. You may be able to using xpath but I am not sure. You need to inherit the action because I think the action defines what records are displayed in the list view. Try editing the domain value manually and then using xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do what Nross2781 is looking for you have to override the ir.actions.act_window for the record.

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="uom_list_action">
    <field name="name">Units Of Measurement</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.uom</field>
    <field name="domain">[("myvariable","!=",True)]</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
```

However you may want to consider adding filters to a search view which would be more flexible. You would also be able to see the records which do not show up by default.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="uom_search_view">
    <field name="name">uom.search</field>
    <field name="model">product.uom</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Units Of Measurement">
            <filter name="my_var_is_true" string="My Variable" domain="[('myvariable','=',True)]"/>
            <filter name="my_var_is_false" string="Not My Variable" domain="[('myvariable','!=',True)]"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: It was not enough to declare this on my end.  I also had to override the menu items, as they simply called the other action window.

I have appended the code to my original post.

Comment: Also, I tried to upvote you, but I have no reputation. It won't let me.  Sorry... :-\

Comment: @phillipstack: with a custom module i would override the original action. Here you only create a new one. But aside from that, your second solution is way better, so i vote it up.

Comment: @Nross2781: you don't need to vote it up, but as questioner you should mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @Nross2781 I would appreciate it if you would mark this correct if it works for you.

Comment: @CZoellner if you wouldnt mind showing an example of the syntax for overriding an action I would appreciate that. It would be a good thing to know.

Comment: At record attribute `id` just use an existing external id in your system. And then change fields you need to change. For example: to override the sales order (not the quotations) menu for sale module use the id "sale.action_orders". Don't forget to set the correct module dependencies in your custom module manifest. For my example you have to add `sale`.

Comment: Thanks I will remember that.

Comment: I have makred this as the correct answer. 

I updated my question to reflect the complete solution.  So basically, I ended up assigning the menu to use the new action.  

I wish there was a way to directly override the action though. If the same action is used in 20 menus, I have to keep overriding the menus, which is cumbersome..